# When exactly __init__() of bpy.types.Panel subclass must be executed?

Tags: python, add-on

I'm getting it run every time I hover a mouse over the button. Isn't it a bug? I thought it must be executed just once on addon activation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `____init____()` function for BPY types (especially UI stuff) can be unpredictable and should not be used.  You likely want to be overloading the `draw()` method instead.

Example:
http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_57_release/bpy.types.Panel.html